# Trying to find the UUID of a USB flash drive using diskutil vs system_profiler

Tags: macos, usb, uuid

I am trying to get the Volume UUID of a USB flash drive using the command line on a Mac. I tried using:

```
system_profiler SPUSBDataType
```

And I get the Volume UUID of two out of the three USB flash drives I tested. The one that doesn’t work—a USBest USB drive—doesn’t seem to show a UUID using system_profiler. But if I use:

```
diskutil info /dev/disk2
```

I can see the drive’s Volume UUID. What am I doing wrong here? Is there one command that I can use to get the Volume UUID for all attached USBs? A command-line method or a method using a Java native library would be nice.

Comment: These are flash drives. I edited my post. And yes, for some of the flash drives, `disk_util` works but `system_profiler` doesn't. By doesn't work, I mean I can't find the volume UUID.

Answer (score -3):

Most Macs like Linux/BSD  do have native support  for `lsblk` or `inxi`:

Try running `lsblk`:

```
lsblk -f 

NAME                            FSTYPE   LABEL UUID                                   MOUNTPOINT

sda2        LVM2_mem       ***AiQ5DT-7xKH-JcMo-xTLa-Tnro-97Tw-X7F6RU***  server.boot-boot    xfs     **e835e0e0-7861-435e-af82-61dbb84f1abd**  /boot
```

Or try running `inxi`:

```
inxi -u 

Partition: ID-1: / size: 5.0G used: 97M (2%) fs: xfs dev: /dev/dm-2
***uuid: a34a76d1-a00b-46f1-9478-ad9ca2ecc548***
           ID-2: /usr size: 15G used: 8.0G (54%) fs: xfs dev: /dev/dm-4
***uuid: df9f4166-36c9-49ce-a7e9-184026ee9536***
```

Another option is  dmesg  (recommend  `tail`ing  dmesg  for cleaner output)

Comment: Odd that the stock ones in the Apple store run both

Comment: worst case you another OS on a live usb/dvd that does i.e. linux or even windows and use disk manager it will be in the properties section.